# How to keep usernames a secret

Tags: php, security, brute-force

After I decided to use usernames for my login system, I'm concerned about the fact that people could always know which usernames are already registered.
I'm using the usernames in the login form, so they still have to be unique, but can I avoid/reduce the risk of people knowing which usernames are in use?

It will make bruteforcing accounts a lot easier when they know half of the query.

On my current system when the user tries to register with a usernames that is already in use they get an error message telling them that this username already exists.

I prefer not to use email verifications for new accounts.

My concern is only bruteforcing. this is the answer I need.
I already force strong passwords by regex, so the main question is:
**Do I have to force randomly generated usernames in order to get better security and protect my users' privacy?**

I am using PHP 7 and PDO.

Comment: exactly how are you going to tell people to choose a different username? "oops, sorry, that won't work" for no reason is just going make your system appear stupid. if you're worried about brute force attacks, then your login system should be able to detect attempts and lock them down. that has nothing to do with revealing the existing of a username.

Comment: So you want user to choose the username, but be notified when it exists, but not let him know that it exists? Doesn't make sense. For security reasons passwords were invented. If you still want to have secret unique usernames, you will have to generate them rather than let the user to choose them.

Comment: @Dagon It would be so until the first attempt to register (measure) it :)

Comment: @Dagon "Hasenpfeffer" should never be used as a username. Warner Bros. has copyrights on that.

Comment: I'm going to tell people to use other usernames by simply saying: "Username is in use, choose another one".

Comment: *Do I have to force randomly generated usernames in order to get better security and protect my users' privacy?* No, most websites use email addresses as usernames, email addresses are not really secret (you can find many online) but if the password is strong enough that's not a security problem.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/), where they are discussing questions like this one.

Comment: To me your reasoning seems to be incorrect. Usually we split the two concerns of identifying the user (by username/id/email) and having a secret (password). Making the identification a secret too, is Security-By-Obscurity, you gain very little, but you make identification more difficult for the user. It's like a second password, you wouldn't require a second password, would you? It would only help against online brute-force attacks, but those attacks are not the real threat because they are very slow anyway.

Comment: Okay, thanks Martin. so I shouldn't threat usernames as a secret? I've almost finished coding the anti-bruteforce system for the website.

Comment: That's right, i would use the username only for identification, and the password for authorization. To brute-force passwords you need access to the hashes (otherwise you are too slow), so you need read access to the database (SQL-injection, lost backup, ...). As soon as you have access to the hashes, you have probably access to the usernames too.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to force users to choose a username sanctioned by the system. If users must, for example, enter their interests as a seed for usernames, you can neatly sidestep the problem.

User: "puppies" and "butterflies".
System: would you like to use "lots-of-puppies" or "puppy-butterfly" as your login name?

I won't claim this isn't annoying, but it is effective, and you can always allow publicly viewable aliases to be set by the user or default to a generic name, as with stack overflow. This will conceal the actual names and comes with the bonus of confusing and annoying bruteforce attackers.

Edit: if you aren't into forcing usernames, you can simply adopt the common Oauth2-or-email-as-username approach. This can be slightly less secure since people's email addresses are often easy or determine.

Comment: im changing my S.O user name to "puppy-butterfly" thanks

Comment: `pirate-ninjas` will soon be popular...

Comment: this is like the porn name game

Comment: Okay. nice idea! thank you. but I'm not really sure how to code something like that

Comment: If that sounds daunting, how about starting with [foswig](http://mrsharpoblunto.github.io/foswig.js/)? It's clean and (IMO) simplifies the entire process. The biggest piece to code is the form for user input, or a large word list to pull from if you don't feel like giving the users full control.

Comment: I have no experience what so ever with Javascript, but it looks quite nice! I will try to add it as an offer for new accounts, do you know better random name generators? built with PHP maybe? Thank you.

Comment: As it happens, I do. [This](https://github.com/nubs/random-name-generator) might be the most straightforward and easiest to install, if you're using Composer. There is also a handy how-to piece [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-gamescripts1/) that spans sections 3-5. I suspect either would be suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea: if the usernames need to be super secret. You can generate random GUID as username when a user register.

This is probably a bit overkill but it will make the usernames almost impossible to guess or brute-force.

On side effect is that users will probably have difficult time memorizing their usernames.

Comment: That was my original idea in my previous thread. using UUIDs or any other long string is an overkill for the regular users, and I don't want to sacrifice so much for security. but thanks for the idea!